# Is there a neat code to swap elements of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, data, filtering

I want to swap the list to make a new list as follows.
The code works but I'm wondering if there is a neat code, or an elegant way to do this.

```
list = {1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, -1, 1};
newlist = {Sequence @@ list[[4 ;; 6]], Sequence @@ list[[1 ;; 3]],
Sequence @@ list[[7 ;; 9]]}
```

Comment: `list[[#]] &  /@  {4 ;; 6, 1 ;; 3, 7 ;; 9}  // Flatten`

Comment: Are you concerned about computational efficiency for very long lists?

Comment: @A.G. that would be good too. What I had in mind was to make it short and easy to understand.

Comment: Then permutations are probably better, in order to avoid duplicating the list.

Comment: Should this go on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 14):

`Permute` exists for reordering lists.

```
Permute[list, Cycles[{{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}]]
```

This swaps entries $1 \leftrightarrow 4$, $2 \leftrightarrow 5$ and $3 \leftrightarrow 6$.

The necessary permutation can be found using `FindPermutation`:

```
FindPermutation[Range@9, {4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9}]
```

> Cycles[{{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}]

Comment: `list[[{4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9}]]` works too.

Answer (score 9):

At least shorter:

```
Flatten@Partition[list, 3][[{2, 1, 3}]]
```

Answer (score 9):

Id suggest using `TakeList`

```
TakeList[ist, {{4, 6}, 3, All}]
TakeList[ist, {{4, 6}, {1, 3}, {1, 3}}]
```

The indices need to be relative to those elements that are not yet taken.

If you have absolute indices given:

```
ist = Range[20];
parts = {{5, 6}, {9, 13}, {1, 4}, {19, 20}, {14, 18}};

Catenate[ist[[# ;; #2]] & @@@ parts]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = Range[9];
swap =  {{2, 5}, {3, 6}};

Fold[SubsetMap[RotateRight, #1, #2] &, list, swap]
```

{1, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = Range[9];
swap = {{2, 5}, {3, 6}};

ds = CreateDataStructure["LinkedList"];

Scan[ds["Append", #] &, list];

ds["SwapPart", ##] & @@@ swap;

Normal @ ds
```

{1, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10}

```
ds["Visualization"]
```

[image]

[Guide to Data Structures](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DataStructures.html)